# How to download excel file in spring boot using HttpHeaders?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http-headers

I am getting a resulting file but in the response I am getting gibberish symbols

here is the code I am trying

```
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getExcel(String filePath) throws Exception {
        try {
            Path excelPath = Paths.get(filePath);
            byte[] excel = Files.readAllBytes(excelPath);
            ByteArrayInputStream excelToByte = new ByteArrayInputStream(excel);
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
            headers.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=ABCGeneratedExcel.xls");

            return ResponseEntity
                    .ok()
                    .headers(headers)
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                    .body(new InputStreamResource(excelToByte));
            }
                catch (NoSuchFileException e) {
                System.out.prinln("does not exist");
            }
```

Comment: Why inline ? Use attachment

Comment: @Eklavya I am still getting the same problem.

Comment: File downloaded properly ? Then open in editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `HttpServletResponse` instead. And let Spring framework initialize it by declaring as Controller method's parameter. Because you will write the excel file as binary stream, do not define the return type.
Then write the response stream after setting the contentType and header for excel downloading.

```
public void getExcel(String filePath, HttpServletResponse response) {
    byte[] excel = Files.readAllBytes(excelPath);
    String fileName = "anyFileName.xlsx"
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
    response.getWriter().write(excel);  // in fact, you need to surround this by try-catch block
}
```

Comment: but we can't write ```byte[] excel``` in ```response.getWriter().write```. write method doesn't have byte[] in input

Answer (score 1):

```
Path filePath = pathToFolder.resolve(fileName).normalize();

        Resource resource = new UrlResource(filePath.toUri());

        if (resource.exists()) {
            return resource;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundException(String.format("File %s not found", fileName));
        }
```

Where path to File - in your directory, and file name - name of file in your directory.

Next step is:

```
Resource resource = service.downloadFile(fileName);

    String contentType = null;

    try {
        contentType = request.getServletContext().getMimeType(resource.getFile().getAbsolutePath());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.info("Could not determine file type");
    }
    if (contentType == null) {
        contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE;
    }
    return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(contentType))
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, String.format(
                    "%s; filename=%s", content.name().toLowerCase(), resource.getFilename()
                    )
            )
            .body(resource);
```

Where first %s - attachment - for downloading, and inline - for rendering file in the browser.
Second %s - name of file (note that if you are storing your file in the file system, use file name with extension).